# Excel macro - html body not well formatted while sending email

Tags: html, vba, excel

I am using excel macro VB script and sending emails to users with Excel content copied in mail body. Excel content is formatted with colors and borders. When the mail is received, formatting is removed and I can only see plain text.

**Code -**

```
With OutMail

.SentOnBehalfOfName = email_from
.To = email_to
.CC = email_cc
.BCC = email_bcc
.subject = subject
.HTMLBody = "Dear All, Please find below today's MIS. <br/>" & RangetoHTML(rng) & "<br/>Regards, <br/> MIS Team <br/>
.Attachments.Add (Attach_Path)
.Send
End With
```

**Function = RangeToHTML** -

```
Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)

    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new temp workbook to pass. Content from the main sheet is copied to temp sheet.
    rng.Copy

    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)

        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

        'This function is used to delete all hidden columns from the sheet that is used for copying mail content.
        'Hidden columns are removed from temp sheet and not from original sheet which is attached with the email.

        Call fn_To_Delete_Hidden_Columns

        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    TempWB.Close SaveChanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing

End Function
```

Please help me here in sending email with html formatting.

Thanks,
Sanket.

Answer (score 1):

Even I faced such a situation, I took a different approach and used a oft file as a template and replaced its content with the required content. This might help you.

```
  Sub TempMail()

    Set otlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set otlNewMail = otlApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("D:\Users\xxxxxx\Desktop\test.oft")
    With otlNewMail
    vTemplateBody = otlNewMail.HTMLBody
    vTemplateSubject = otlNewMail.Subject
    .Close 1
    End With
    x = 2
    Do While Range("B" & x).Formula <> ""

    Set otlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set otlNewMail = otlApp.CreateItem(0)
    With otlNewMail
    .To = Range("C" & x).Value
    '.SentOnBehalfOfName = vFrom
    '.Bcc = vToList
    .Subject = Range("D" & x).Value


    TempBody = Replace(vTemplateBody, "xxxxx", Range("I" & x).Value)  'Name updated
    TempBody = Replace(TempBody, "xxxx**xx",  Range("B" & x).Value) 'temp changed
    'TempBody = Replace(vTemplateBody, "Remove -", "Remove -" & Range("H" & x).Value) 'Remove changed
    TempBody = Replace(TempBody, "Add", "Add -" & Range("L" & x).Value) 'Add changed

    .HTMLBody = TempBody

    .Display
    End With
    x = x + 1
    Loop
    End Sub
```